# How to draw a straight line in heatmap plot

Tags: r, plot

I am making a heatmap for some data and want to add a straight line between each set of samples. It seems like `abline` doesn't work well on `heatmap`.

Any idea what function I can use for this purpose?

Comment: Please post the code, and show where you want the connections. "between each set of samples" will lead to a total disaster-plot. lines works with heatmap, but finding the coordinates is tricky.

Comment: For finding the coordinates I use the order of the rownames (samples) or columns (variables). Let's say I would want to draw a vertical line between each variable using the `add.expr` argument: `add.expr = abline(v = seq_along(colnames(mtcars))+0.5)`. The value `0.5` offsets the line to the right so that it is positioned between the variables.

Answer (score 8):

You have to use the `add.expr` argument. This example found [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2006-January/086609.html) might be usefull:

```
x  <- as.matrix(mtcars)
rc <- rainbow(nrow(x), start=0, end=.3)
cc <- rainbow(ncol(x), start=0, end=.3)
hv <- heatmap(x, col = cm.colors(256), scale="column",
               RowSideColors = rc, ColSideColors = cc, margin=c(5,10),
               xlab = "specification variables", ylab= "Car Models",
               main = "heatmap(<Mtcars data>, ..., scale = \"column\")",
               # IMPORTANT BIT HERE
               add.expr = abline(h=5, v=2))
```